# Average time between two datetimes for this month and last month

Tags: mysql

We have a table with two fields tkTimeOpen and tkTimeClosed. We need to find the average wait time for this month and last month. I've been unable to get the right SQL query to pull out what I need.

This is how the date-time is recorded; 2017-01-25 10:35

This Month's Average;

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,tkTimeOpen,tkTimeClose)) * 1.0 
           / (SELECT COUNT(*) * 1.0 FROM e_ticket)
FROM e_ticket
WHERE YEAR(tkTimeOpen) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(tkTimeOpen) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 0 MONTH)
```

Last Month's Average

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,tkTimeOpen,tkTimeClose)) * 1.0 
           / (SELECT COUNT(*) * 1.0 FROM e_ticket)
FROM e_ticket
WHERE YEAR(tkTimeOpen) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(tkTimeOpen) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

I've tried a lot of variations but it doesn't give the desired output.
If anyone could help that would be great!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the average minutes for last month and this month combined:

```
SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, tkTimeOpen, tkTimeClose)) 
FROM e_ticket 
WHERE tkTimeOpen >= DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

If you still need to get the averages separately, you can keep your WHERE clause similar to what you have...

For this month:

```
SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, tkTimeOpen, tkTimeClose)) 
FROM e_ticket 
WHERE YEAR(tkTimeOpen) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(tkTimeOpen) = MONTH(NOW());
```

And for last month:

```
SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, tkTimeOpen, tkTimeClose)) 
FROM e_ticket 
WHERE YEAR(tkTimeOpen) = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(tkTimeOpen) = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. One function you could use is `TIMESTAMPDIFF` - not `DATEDIFF`
2. You can use `AVG()` instead of `SUM() / COUNT()`

```
SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,tkTimeOpen,tkTimeClose))
FROM e_ticket
WHERE YEAR(tkTimeOpen)  = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  AND MONTH(tkTimeOpen) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```